# Error: 'EOFError: Ran out of input'. I am trying to read a pickle file to generate predictions

Tags: python, pickle

I am getting the above error as 'EOFError: Ran out of input'.
Below is the code:

```
from flask import Flask,render_template,url_for,request
import pandas as pd 

import pickle

# load the model from disk
loaded_model=pickle.load(open('random_forest_regression_model.pkl', 'rb'))
app = Flask(__name__)
```

Comment: Is your program looking in the right directory for the pkl file?

Comment: Yes, I think I found out the error. The pkl file which I am trying to open is empty. I created another pkl file, and it works now.

Comment: Great, Anil! You might want to submit it as an answer, just in case someone else encounters this same situation in the future. (yes, you are allowed to answer your own questions).

Answer (score 0):

The above error happened as the pickle file was either corrupted or empty. So, I have created the pickle file again, then
I’ve run the command
‘python app.py’

It worked!